# Typescript element has type any because expression

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to check if my req body has an action that i can handle, the code looks like this:

```
if (!req.body.action || !commands[req.body.action]) {
  ...
}
```

Now, commands is imported from a separate file that looks like this:

```
export const commands = {
  copy: require('./copyDocument'),
  move: require('./moveDocument')
};

export default commands;
```

Where copy, from ./copyDocument looks like this:

```
const copyDocument = async function() {
   ...
};

export default copyDocument;
```

The error i'm getting looks like this:

```
TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{ copy: any; move: any; }'.
```

How can i fix this error, knowing that this piece of code worked in plain .js

Answer (score 0):

You can create Commands type and use keyof Commands.

```
interface Commands {
  copy: any;
  move: any;
}

export const commands: Commands = {
  copy: require("./copyDocument"),
  move: require("./moveDocument"),
};

const action = req.body.action as keyof Commands;
```

Comment: This works, with the mention that i will have to reuse this in other components, so i would like to have it in another file, and if so, i don't know how to create the action const.